# What should we expect from a <script> element that is distributed into a shadow root's slot?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

I've noticed that `<script>` elements can be distributed into (assigned to) slot elements in a shadow root.

What does this mean? What's the expected behavior? Or does the script tag behave as normal, executed in global context regardless of if it is ever distributed into a shadow tree?